# Why not target button tag in CSS instead of a class?

Tags: css, html, naming-conventions

Why don’t common toolkits like Bootstrap target the button tag directly, but define classes like btn and btn-default instead?

I cannot understand why `<button class="btn btn-default">` is any better than just `<button>`. Is there a technical reason to prefer the classes instead of the tag, or it's just a matter of code styling?

Edit:
I get that a btn class can be reused in other elements, but why not apply it by default on the button tag?

Comment: to downvoter: can you to explain the reason?

Comment: Because the `.btn` class can be applied to multiple elements, like `input`, `a` and `span`.

Comment: its so that the class is reusable.

Comment: I don't think this question merits being closed for being primarily opinion based. (For other reasons, maybe, idk). The question asks if there are any technical reason for favouring one over the other, and that can be answered with facts about the differences between the two.

Comment: Agreed. This is an aspect of application design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily any better or worse - different approaches can be useful in different situations.

The primary reason to use a class over an element selector is twofold:

- The class can be applied to different kinds of elements (maybe you want an `<a>` element to have the same styling as a button.
- You have control over when the class is applied (maybe you have certain `<button>` elements that do not require the same styling as others.. you can now opt to not include that class for this button)

Which basically boils down to flexibility. There are other potential differences too. Class selectors have higher specificity than element selectors, for example.